# How can I force the size of a Java (.jar) application window?

Tags: java, swing, jar, resize, size

I have an old .jar file that creates a main window with some textboxes for settings.

The problem is that some textboxes doesn't appear in the window (but they exist), if you lower the computer screen resolution they appear, but with higher resolutions, they disappear.

I tried to decompile the .jar file, but no success...

Since I cannot resize the window in any way (size seems to be fixed), is there a way to force it to be resized or set some Java VM parameters for this purpose?

The loader is ["JarRsrcLoader"](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/plain/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/jar%20in%20jar%20loader/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoader.java). I attach an image showing the problem in Win10:

[image: Jarfile not showing all textboxes]

(They are not only cut, there are more textboxes).

Comment: _I tried to decompile the .jar file, but no success..._ Well you will need to uncompile the project (*.class) to update the java then rebuild it. (If you don't have the source). There is an option for hidpi screen for the JVM, but can't remember the option

Comment: Are you referring to *this* [`JarRsrcLoader`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/plain/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/jar%20in%20jar%20loader/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoader.java)? If not, link to where it was downloaded.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes i'm referring to that loader you linked.

Comment: @AxelH I have already decompiled the *.class files and tried to modify the source code, but it doesn't work... some code is missing. I will really appreciate an option like the one you say for the JVM...

Comment: This will only resize internal componenet with a ratio for High-Density screens. Not even sure this works correctly. Well, you should search for the source code, if this is internal application, this should be somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way to scale the Java application to a lower resolution and see it adequately, **only for Linux** (but it was what I was searching).

**From this source** (askubuntu.com): [script to fix scaling of java applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526484/fix-scaling-of-java-based-applications-for-a-high-dpi-screen).

It provides python scripts to adjust the resolution of certain applications (statically and dynamically) when opened (on a high dpi screen). This solution works for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I asked Mr Google for a Windows tool to make unresizable windows resizeable. Got several matches, here is a short list:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11799/turn-non-resizeable-windows-into-rezieable-windows/
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-resize-an-unresizable-window-or-dialog-box/
http://www.ghacks.net/2012/06/18/resize-windows-with-fixed-sizes/

Comment: I'm looking forward to a more simple solution, that allow me to redistribute the .jar and execute it in different operating systems. I'm not too interested in external programs, but thanks anyway :)